# Convert from rtf 2 pdf using php

Tags: php

i will like to ask  if there is any script or any help on how to convert rtf to pdf using a php script, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard about such thing, but you can call other program, which converts it. But you must have the permission to instal that program to your hosting.

Comment: Ok, i suppose this is the way to go.
Wanting to have a platform independent solution, but will have to use a binary for linux and windows.
Thanks for your reply